# error cs0029 how to fix this error please

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion

I dont know how to fix I've tried everything!!!

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `rb.rotation` is of type `Quaternion` and `angle` is of type `float` which are not the same. You have a field for an angle which it has to rotate. The code below set's the rotation of rigid body in such a way that only it's rotation along X-axis is set.

```cs
void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    float y = Quaternion.identity.eulerAngles.y;
    float z = Quaternion.identity.eulerAngles.z;

    rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle, y, z);
}
```

Comment: so would i put this in the update method instead of what i have now??

Comment: @ritter_dev, yes

Comment: Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs(19,35): error CS0103: The name 'direction' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ritter_dev, you have to add this code below your `Vector3 direction = `code. I have updated my answer, take a look at it and mention if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is already mentioned, here is just a compact version of that

```
rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * angle);
```

This is an optimal option for working on a single dimension, instead of all three.

P.S. use `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.forward` to change y and z too.
check static properties on https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Comment: so would i put this in the update method instead of what i have now??

Comment: Not quite, you should change last line in your update method with my code, `rb.rotation = angle;` -> `rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * angle);`